# Access local postgres with SequelPro

Tags: postgresql, sequelpro

I am using Sequel Pro and want to access my local Postgres DB.

When I get prompted in sequel pro to add connection details for my db I oblige:

[image]

And then when I click connect I get:

[image]

I am on a mac running Catalina 10.15.3.

The database I am running is a postgres installed with brew. When I run `brew services list` I get:

[image]

My application (a laravel application using laravel valet) can access the database.

What can be wrong? I have some thoughts...

If I enter my db and type: `select inet_server_addr( ), inet_server_port( );`

I get this output:

```
 inet_server_addr | inet_server_port
------------------+------------------
                  |
(1 row)
```

And I think that I should get 127.0.0.1 at least in the `inet_server_addr` column....

I don't know if this is a hint of where the error might be or not.

So, to summarize. My thoughts go in the direction that I am not running the postgres server 100% correctly... BUT i still think it is strange that my app can access the db but not Sequel Pro...

If I typ *127.0.0.1* in my browser I get a *404 - Not Found*

How do I do to be able to access my local postgres with Sequel Pro?

Comment: Do not paste images of text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As *a_horse_with_no_name* pointed out in the comments, the website states that Sequel Pro is for MySQL databases, not Postgres:

> "Sequel Pro is a fast, easy-to-use Mac database management application for working with **MySQL** databases."

[image]